# Mixins as an instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, class, multiple-inheritance, mixins, entity-component-system

I'm using an entity-component system. I've defined some components as ES6 classes, and I can create instances of those components by calling their constructors with `new`. I'm trying to use these class instances as mixins. I've found that using `Object.assign` doesn't copy the methods of those instances onto my target object because the methods are bound to the object's prototype.

I've found a hacky solution as follows:

```js
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  return Object
    .getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
    .concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.__proto__))
    .filter(name => (name !== "constructor"))
}

function assembleFromComponents(obj, ...cmp) {
  for(let i of cmp) {
    for(let j of getAllPropertyNames(i)) {
      obj[j] = i[j]
    }
  }
}
```

This method is not ideal because it doesn't access the component's full prototype chain, although I don't think I'll need it anyway. However, upon inspection, getters and setters don't appear to work.

Is there a better way to use a class instance as a mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably wouldn't define mixins using `class` syntax. I'd define them as objects:

```
const myMixin = {
    doThis() {
        // ...
    },
    doThat() {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
};
```

One issue with `class` syntax is that `super` may not work as you expect, because even after being copied, the methods will still refer to their **original** home object. (Or that may be what you expect in which case you're fine.) More on this below.

But if you want to use `class` syntax, you can define an `Object.assign`-like function that applies all of the methods and other properties from the entire chain via [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) and [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors), which will copy getters and setters. Something like (off the cuff, not tested):

```
function assignAll(target, source, inherited = false) {
    // Start from the prototype and work upward, so that overrides work

    let chain;
    if (inherited) {
        // Find the first prototype after `Object.prototype`
        chain = [];
        let p = source;
        do {
            chain.unshift(p);
            p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);
        } while (p && p !== Object.prototype);
    } else {
        chain = [source];
    }
    for (const obj of chain) {
        // Get the descriptors from this object
        const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
        // We don't want to copy the constructor or __proto__ properties
        delete descriptors.constructor;
        delete descriptors.__proto__;
        // Apply them to the target
        Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Using it:

```
assignAll(Example.prototype, Mixin.prototype);
```

Live Example:

```js
function assignAll(target, source, inherited = false) {
    // Start from the prototype and work upward, so that overrides work

    let chain;
    if (inherited) {
        // Find the first prototype after `Object.prototype`
        chain = [];
        let p = source;
        do {
            chain.unshift(p);
            p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);
        } while (p && p !== Object.prototype);
    } else {
        chain = [source];
    }
    for (const obj of chain) {
        // Get the descriptors from this object
        const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
        // We don't want to copy the constructor or __proto__ properties
        delete descriptors.constructor;
        delete descriptors.__proto__;
        // Apply them to the target
        Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
    }
    return target;
}

class Example {
    method() {
        console.log("this is method");
    }
}
const mixinFoos = new WeakMap();
class Mixin {
    mixinMethod() {
        console.log("mixin method");
    }
    get foo() {
        let value = mixinFoos.get(this);
        if (value !== undefined) {
            value = String(value).toUpperCase();
        }
        return value;
    }
    set foo(value) {
        return mixinFoos.set(this, value);
    }
}

assignAll(Example.prototype, Mixin.prototype, true);

const e = new Example();
e.foo = "hi";
console.log(e.foo);
// HI
```

Here's an example where the mixin is a subclass and uses `super`, just to demonstrate what `super` means in that context:

```js
function assignAll(target, source, inherited = false) {
    // Start from the prototype and work upward, so that overrides work

    let chain;
    if (inherited) {
        // Find the first prototype after `Object.prototype`
        chain = [];
        let p = source;
        do {
            chain.unshift(p);
            p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);
        } while (p && p !== Object.prototype);
    } else {
        chain = [source];
    }
    for (const obj of chain) {
        // Get the descriptors from this object
        const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
        // We don't want to copy the constructor or __proto__ properties
        delete descriptors.constructor;
        delete descriptors.__proto__;
        // Apply them to the target
        Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
    }
    return target;
}

class Example {
    method() {
        console.log("this is Example.method");
    }
}

class MixinBase {
    method() {
        console.log("this is MixinBase.method");
    }
}

class Mixin extends MixinBase {
    method() {
        super.method();
        console.log("this is Mixin.method");
    }
}

assignAll(Example.prototype, Mixin.prototype, true);

const e = new Example();
e.method();
// "this is MixinBase.method"
// "this is Mixin.method"
```

---

You've said you want to use class *instances* as mixins. The above works just fine doing that. Here's an example:

```js
function assignAll(target, source, inherited = false) {
    // Start from the prototype and work upward, so that overrides work

    let chain;
    if (inherited) {
        // Find the first prototype after `Object.prototype`
        chain = [];
        let p = source;
        do {
            chain.unshift(p);
            p = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);
        } while (p && p !== Object.prototype);
    } else {
        chain = [source];
    }
    for (const obj of chain) {
        // Get the descriptors from this object
        const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
        // We don't want to copy the constructor or __proto__ properties
        delete descriptors.constructor;
        delete descriptors.__proto__;
        // Apply them to the target
        Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
    }
    return target;
}

class Example {
    method() {
        console.log("this is Example.method");
    }
}

class MixinBase {
    method() {
        console.log("this is MixinBase.method");
    }
}

const mixinFoos = new WeakMap();
class Mixin extends MixinBase {
    constructor(value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }
    mixinMethod() {
        console.log(`mixin method, value = ${this.value}`);
    }
    get foo() {
        let value = mixinFoos.get(this);
        if (value !== undefined) {
            value = String(value).toUpperCase();
        }
        return value;
    }
    set foo(value) {
        return mixinFoos.set(this, value);
    }
    method() {
        super.method();
        console.log("this is Mixin.method");
    }
}

// Here I'm using it on `Example.prototype`, but it could be on an
// `Example` instance as well
assignAll(Example.prototype, new Mixin(42), true);

const e = new Example();
e.mixinMethod();
// "mixin method, value = 42"
e.method();
// "this is MixinBase.method"
// "this is Mixin.method"
e.foo = "hi";
console.log(e.foo);
// "HI"
```

But really, you can design it however you want to; `assignAll` is just an example, as are the runnable ones above. The key things here are:

1. Use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` to get property descriptors and `Object.defineProperties` (or their singular counterparts, `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and `defineProperty`), so that accessor methods get transferred as accessors.
2. Work from the base prototype up to the instance, so that overriding at each level works correctly.
3. `super` will continue to work in its original inheritance chain, not in the new location the mixin has been copied to.

Comment: Yes, almost always I've seen mixins defined as objects. What I wanted to do was to allow for slight variations in the numbers, etc. of those mixins. A class syntax seemed like the easiest way to maintain readability for that purpose. Edit: I just tested it and unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @EnderShadow8 - (I've updated the answer with a runnable example.) One concern with using `class` syntax that I'd have is `super`, which won't behave as expected when used in a mixin. (Well, okay, it depends on what you expect. :-D )

Comment: @EnderShadow8 - Also just updated to show an example using `super`, which revealed a stoopid bug in my original `assignAll`, which I've fixed. :-)

Comment: My question wasn't about using a class as a mixin though, it was about using a class _instance_ as a mixin, which allows me to pass in arguments to the constructor. My problem was that the methods were bound to the prototype rather than the instance. I'm afraid we were talking about completely different problems. I'll try to clarify my question.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 - The above works just fine if you use it with instances rather than prototypes. I'll add an example.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 - I've added an example of using a class instance as a mixin.